# How to check the current java classpath at runtime

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, java-9, java-11

Using JDK 8, I have simply been using the following:

```
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).getURLs();
```

It appears this breaks in JDK 9+ as the ClassLoader is no longer a URLClassLoader.

How would I go about getting the current classpath if it has been modified by multiple classloaders?